# Undefined when console.log in the browser

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows:

```
let smartContractState = await zilliqa.blockchain.getSmartContractState(contractAddress);

let users_map = smartContractState.result.users; //users is a mapping as users[getAddress]=name
```

Till this point everything works fine as I can see the result by `console.log(users_map)`;

0x502a2dcaec7ce8a4790141e4fe4753e7edb6381a: "name"
0x812e4a8ec02a01a398141a6546822b1ed0d9acbf: "Naveen"
0xdfe5c37484fa6b83bac3e0673671cb19577c7729: "world"
0xfff4903b3b5739d5d79f73286d05db82677a29e6: "kumar"

---

But when I do this:

```
let username = users_map[getAddress] ;//getAddress : is input by the user.
```

where getAddress = 0x502a2dcaec7ce8a4790141e4fe4753e7edb6381a

and print it using `console.log(username);`  it says `undefined`

---

I am providing the link for reference:https://devex.zilliqa.com/address/0x25af495166897a7b1c095f8c3af730446d79c142?network=https://dev-api.zilliqa.com
Now you can check the state by going to the state section.
Also `getSmartContractState` is a method defined in the zilliqa.js library.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the value of `users_map`?(you can update your question to include that)

Comment: Is getAddress variable somewhat similar to 0x502a2dcaec7ce8a4790141e4fe4753e7edb6381a?Say I input getAddress to be abcd(which does not exist inside users_map) then users_map[getAddress] will be undefined as there is no entry inside users_map having key abcd. It would be easier if you could paste the output of users_map and getAddress.

Comment: I have edited the question and have provided the value of users_map.

Comment: Are you sure getAddress has the value that you're expecting? try doing a console log right before
let username = users_map[getAddress]

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that getAddress does not have the value you're expecting to have. Probably undefined, the rest looks good so I bet that's your problem

Comment: Thanks Leandro for noticing that. It's working fine now.

Answer (score -2):

smartContractState.result.user is not an array so you can't select based on key ( users_map[getAddress] ). My thought is to use a for loop and check if if matches getAddress.

Comment: users_map[getAddress] that's not an array, that's accessing an objects attribute

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).